# nuxtjs - how to build a project in a specific version

Tags: nuxt.js

I want to create a project in nuxt js in version 2.15.8. I researched, tried to do some ways that I know but it does not work. Does anyone know if this is possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following these steps https://nuxtjs.org/docs/get-started/installation/#manual-installation
and replace :

- `yarn add nuxt` by `yarn add nuxt@2.15.8` if you use yarn
- `npm install nuxt` by `npm install nuxt@2.15.8` if you use npm

Comment: This, by default will create `^2.15.8`, meaning that it will still be able to go higher (to something like `2.45.7`) as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/8816585 So not what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a very specific in your `package.json` like that

```json
{
  "name": "my-cool-project",
  [...]
  "dependencies": {
    "nuxt": "2.15.8" //  notice that there is no ^2.15.8 here, it's important!
  },
}
```